# Angular router: how to manupulate every route data in runtime / dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular2-observables, rxjs6, angular-observable

The problem:
external breadcrumb implementation forces to use such construct for routes:

```js
export const routes = {
    path: 'xx',
    component: xxComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'someTitle' //<-- breadcrumb requirement
    },
}
```

current project has something like:

```js
export const routes = {
    path: 'xx',
    component: xxComponent,
    data: {
      options: {title: 'some.title'} //<-- current project, will be translated.
    },
}
```

the data from `options`will be translated then.

since the breadcrumb cannot translate, and needs another `data` structure, it would be nice, to set the `data.title = translate(data.options.title)` dynamically on **every** route call (full routes tree, since breadcrumb traverse it)

the endresult, should be then:

```js
export const routes = {
    path: 'xx',
    component: xxComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'translatedSomeTitle' //<--should be dynamically added
      options: {title: 'some.title'}
    },
}
```

How to write such interceptor?
Is there a better way to solve the problem?

One solution could be a resolver `... data: {title: TitleResolver, ...` , but i dont want to write resolver on every route definition, and probably later remove, if breadcrumb will be improved.

Comment: Have you thought about a superclass/service that does that at component creation ? You could probably even make a decorator for that. Otherwise, feel free to provide a [mcve] in a sandbox so that we can play with it.

Comment: @trichetriche do you mean the breadcrumb? It would be good solution if the breadcrumb would be good extendable. But the implementation is hard there. So i should rewrite like full breadcrumb then and lose the support from the dev team of the component. Need rewrite it then on every breadcrumb update :/ But still possible solution for all routes at once, thx.